# Dictionary<BigInteger[],BigInteger[]> does not return value when key is clearly correct. Dictionary is of RSA Keys for my custom RSA algorithm

Tags: c#, dictionary, rsa, biginteger

I am currently working on creating a RSA test for a program of mine, this is the debug to make sure everything works before I implement it.

I know the RSA algorithm itself works, the problem lies with the `Dictionary` of `<Biginteger[],Biginteger[]>` where it is it form `<publickey, privatekey>` where public key is an array {e,n} and private key {d,n}.

When generating the keys it adds both to the dictionary successfully however when it puts in the public key to return the private key it says it isnt a valid key.

Unsure why and is bothering me as the debug (attached) would show it should work.
(with regards to why im doing a strange ASCII translation thing and not using the RSA properly it is simply a demo and in my system i just need to encrypt and decrypt values -1<x<999)

The reason for turning from form string "e,n" to an array {e,n} is due to the nature of how i will be transferring the data across a socket so will be in that form.

Any Ideas or help to why it cant find the value would be great :)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<BigInteger[], BigInteger[]> RSA_KEYS = new Dictionary<BigInteger[], BigInteger[]>();

        //recipitent receives public key in form e,n
        //splits into Biginteger array : {e,n}
        string publickeystring = (PublicKeyRequest(RSA_KEYS));
        BigInteger[] publickeyresponse = Array.ConvertAll(publickeystring.Split(','), BigInteger.Parse);
        Console.WriteLine("Public Key Requested: " + publickeystring);

        foreach (var item in RSA_KEYS)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key[0] + ", "+ item.Key[1] + ":" + item.Value[0] + ", " + item.Value[1]);
        }


        //creates message to encrypt
        string input = InputToAscii();

        //recipitent encrypts message
        BigInteger a = encrypt(publickeyresponse, input);
        Console.WriteLine("Encrypted Value = " + a);

        //using public key sent back from recipitent it will find private key in dictionary to use to decrypt
        BigInteger b = decrypt(RSA_KEYS[publickeyresponse], a);
        Console.WriteLine("Decrypted Value = " + b);

        Console.WriteLine(AsciiToOutput(b));
        
        
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string PublicKeyRequest(Dictionary<BigInteger[], BigInteger[]> RSA_KEYS)
    {
        KeyValuePair<BigInteger[], BigInteger[]> Keys = GenerateKeys();
        Console.WriteLine("added public key to dict: " + Keys.Key[0] + "," + Keys.Key[1]);
        BigInteger[] publickey = Keys.Key;
        RSA_KEYS.Add(Keys.Key, Keys.Value);
        return (publickey[0] + "," + publickey[1]);

    }

    


    private static KeyValuePair<BigInteger[], BigInteger[]> GenerateKeys()
    {
        int p = 4201; //default use 61  4201
        int q = 4007; //default use 53  4007
        int n = p * q;

        Console.WriteLine("p = " + p + ", q = " + q + ", " + "n = " + n);
        // n = 3233.

        // compute the totient, phi
        int ϕn = (p - 1) * (q - 1);
        Console.WriteLine("ϕ(n) = " + ϕn);
        // phi = 3120.


        //e for random number which 1 < e < ϕn and is co prime of ϕn
        Random rn = new Random();
        bool found = false;
        BigInteger e = 0;

        while (found == false)
        {
            e = rn.Next(1, ϕn);
            if (Coprime(ϕn, e) == true)
            {
                break;
            }
        }


        Console.WriteLine("e = " + e);

        // Using the extended euclidean algorithm, find 'd' which satisfies
        // where (d * e) mod ϕn = 1 find d

        BigInteger d = 0;


        for (int k = 1; k < ϕn; k++)
        {
            if ((k * e) % ϕn == 1)
            {
                d = k;
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("d = " + d);

        BigInteger[] public_key = new BigInteger[] { e, n }; //(e = 17, n = 3233)
        Console.WriteLine("Public key: e = " + e + " n = " + n);
        BigInteger[] private_key = new BigInteger[] { d, n }; //(d = 2753, n = 3233)
        Console.WriteLine("Private key: d = " + d + " n = " + n);
        return new KeyValuePair<BigInteger[], BigInteger[]>(public_key,private_key);
    }

    private static BigInteger encrypt(BigInteger[] PublicKey, string input)
    {
        BigInteger m = BigInteger.Parse(input); //m = message
        BigInteger c = eMod(m, PublicKey[0], PublicKey[1]); //cipher text = (message ^ e) mod n
        return c;
    }

    private static BigInteger decrypt(BigInteger[] PrivateKey, BigInteger c)
    {
        BigInteger f = eMod(c, PrivateKey[0], PrivateKey[1]); //result test = cipher ^ d mod n

        return f;
    }

    private static BigInteger eMod(BigInteger a, BigInteger b, BigInteger c) //where a^b % c;
    {
        //base case
        if (b == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (b % 2 == 0)
        {
            BigInteger d = eMod(a, b / 2, c);
            //int result = d * d % c;
            return ((d * d) % c);
        }
        else
        {
            return ((a % c) * eMod(a, b - 1, c)) % c;
        }
    }

    private static BigInteger GetGCDByModulus(BigInteger value1, BigInteger value2)
    {
        while (value1 != 0 && value2 != 0)
        {
            if (value1 > value2)
                value1 %= value2;
            else
                value2 %= value1;
        }
        return BigInteger.Max(value1, value2);
    }

    private static bool Coprime(BigInteger value1, BigInteger value2)
    {
        return GetGCDByModulus(value1, value2) == 1;
    }

    private static string InputToAscii()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter values to encrypt:");
        char[] input = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray(); //-1 < input < 999;

        //char[] input = "-1".ToCharArray();
        string AsciiInput = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            AsciiInput += ((int)input[i]).ToString();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(AsciiInput);
        return AsciiInput;
    }

    private static string AsciiToOutput(BigInteger input)
    {
        string inputstring = input.ToString();
        string output = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < inputstring.Length / 2; i++)
        {
            output += (char)Convert.ToInt32((inputstring.Substring(i * 2, 2)));
        }
        return output;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: An array does not make for a good key in a dictionary as it will have reference equality, which means that another array with the same values will not match.  I'd suggest using a value tuple instead like `Dictionary<(BigInteger, BigInteger), (BigInteger, BigInteger)>`

Comment: Is this supposed to be rsa? Why aren't you using the built in types for handing that, which all use byte arrays as keys?

Comment: Nitpick: That algorithm you're using to find `d` is *not* the extended euclidean algorithm.

Comment: *"...where it is it form <publickey, privatekey>..."* -- Is this a typo?